# OpenVpn configuration

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, openvpn

I am trying to configure openvpn for ubuntu 14.04
I followed the instructions from https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html. According to the instruction i must download easyrsa separately and initialze PKI in the easy-rsa subdirectory.

```
. ./vars
./clean-all
./build-ca

I'm lost in these steps.
```

Comment: Easy-rsa are scripts to help you configure OpenVPN. How are you lost in these steps, cannot find the easy-rsa directory?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first install easy-rsa with this command:

sudo apt-get install easy-rsa

I suggest then moving asy rsa intoyour openvpn directory:

cp -r /usr/share/easy-rsa/ /etc/openvpn

Then create a directory for the keys:

mkdir /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys

Then you can run:

cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa

source ./vars

./clean-all

./build-ca

Answer (score 1):

you can use this script to easily install and configure openvpn on your server with a single command

```
wget git.io/vpn --no-check-certificate -O openvpn-install.sh; bash openvpn-install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

you should edit the floder write permission.
sudo chmod +x openvpn